# Sharepoint Scoped External Content Type List - Update and Delete not Working RESTFul

Tags: javascript

SharePoint 2013

I currently have a OData service created and I have bee successful in reading and Insert to database it references, via javascript.  When I am doing a DELETE or UPDATE I get the following  error.  Normal list allow deletion and update.

Any advice greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.AuthenticationException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Message from External System : 'LobSystem (External System) returned authentication error.'.\"}}}"
```

```
$.ajax({
        url: data.__metadata.uri,
        type: "DELETE",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-Http-Method": "DELETE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (e) {
            alert("deleted");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer my question.

1. Created a new AppPool
2. Changed the odata service application in IIS to use this app pool.
3. App Pool .Net 4.0 Integrated.
4. IIS web application for the data service is using Anonymous Auth, set to App Pool identity credentials.
5. In Application Pool Advanced Settings in IIS changed Identity to a system windows account on my domain.
6. Added data service application folder permission of Full Control for the new Created App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

try using this format:

```
function onDeleteProduct(productId) {

  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Products')/items(" + productId + ")";

  var requestHeaders = {
    "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "If-Match": "*" // delete the item even if another user has updated it since we last fetched it
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "DELETE",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function(){
      alert("Deleted product");
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Failed to delete product");
    }
  });
```

}

Comment: hi there i tried the above syntax, with this same error. Could this be an IIS issue for the odata webservice?.